# How to fix MySQL Workbench 8 crashing on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: mysql-workbench

Recently I started experiencing issues with MySQL Workbench 8 in which actions cause it to crash after the initial load. Initial load works fine and I configure a connection.  I then close workbench, re-open, and try to connect and it crashes. At this point I can also open it for a few seconds (without doing anything) and it will crash.

A few observations:

- This doesn't seem to happen if it loads without any connections.
- This happens consistently after I load it a second time.
- Even if `~./mysql` is deleted (and therefore any connections), it will still crash, even on trying to hit "Help" or "Add Connection"

Versions:

- Pop! OS 18.10
- MySQL Workbench 8.0.15

I've tried:

- installing from MySQL site with `.deb`
- installing from `apt`
- uninstalling and purging all references to MySQL
- installing previous versions of workbench

This is the output of `gdb`

```sh
<pre>(mysql-workbench-bin:3163): Gtk-<font color="#FFCE51"><b>WARNING</b></font> **: <font color="#3465A4">13:50:01.393</font>: drawing failure for widget &apos;gtkmm__GtkEntry&apos;: out of memory

(mysql-workbench-bin:3163): Gtk-<font color="#FFCE51"><b>WARNING</b></font> **: <font color="#3465A4">13:50:01.393</font>: drawing failure for widget &apos;gtkmm__GtkBox&apos;: out of memory

(mysql-workbench-bin:3163): Gtk-<font color="#FFCE51"><b>WARNING</b></font> **: <font color="#3465A4">13:50:01.393</font>: drawing failure for widget &apos;gtkmm__GtkFixed&apos;: out of memory

(mysql-workbench-bin:3163): glibmm-<font color="#F15D22"><b>ERROR</b></font> **: <font color="#3465A4">13:50:01.393</font>: 
unhandled exception (type std::exception) in signal handler:
what: std::bad_alloc


Thread 1 &quot;mysql-workbench&quot; received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00007ffff61d59f5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff61d59f5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff61d6a9d in g_log_default_handler () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff61d6cef in g_logv () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff61d6edf in g_log () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff536ce2f in Glib::exception_handlers_invoke() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm-2.4.so.1
#5  0x00007ffff5deca71 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1
#6  0x00007ffff68dbf9b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#7  0x00007ffff688767f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#8  0x00007ffff62afb6d in g_closure_invoke () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#9  0x00007ffff62c23ee in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#10 0x00007ffff62caf43 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#11 0x00007ffff62cbecf in g_signal_emit () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#12 0x00007ffff6894142 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#13 0x00007ffff667e9fa in gtk_container_propagate_draw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#14 0x00007ffff667eacd in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#15 0x00007ffff6630d94 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#16 0x00007ffff6683b5d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#17 0x00007ffff6688832 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#18 0x00007ffff6633621 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#19 0x00007ffff5dec68e in Gtk::Widget_Class::draw_callback(_GtkWidget*, _cairo*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1
#20 0x00007ffff68dbf9b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#21 0x00007ffff688767f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#22 0x00007ffff62afa81 in g_closure_invoke () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#23 0x00007ffff62c2124 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#24 0x00007ffff62caf43 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#25 0x00007ffff62cbecf in g_signal_emit () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#26 0x00007ffff6894142 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#27 0x00007ffff667e9fa in gtk_container_propagate_draw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#28 0x00007ffff667eacd in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#29 0x00007ffff679d9f6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#30 0x00007ffff6885180 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#31 0x00007ffff6683b5d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#32 0x00007ffff6688832 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#33 0x00007ffff6885e8d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#34 0x00007ffff6893fe4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#35 0x00007ffff667e9fa in gtk_container_propagate_draw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#36 0x00007ffff667eacd in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#37 0x00007ffff67cba6b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#38 0x00007ffff6683b5d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#39 0x00007ffff6688832 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#40 0x00007ffff67c9dc1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#41 0x00007ffff5dec68e in Gtk::Widget_Class::draw_callback(_GtkWidget*, _cairo*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1
#42 0x00007ffff6893fe4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#43 0x00007ffff667e9fa in gtk_container_propagate_draw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#44 0x00007ffff667eacd in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#45 0x00007ffff6630d94 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
--Type &lt;RET&gt; for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--c
#46 0x00007ffff6683b5d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#47 0x00007ffff6688832 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#48 0x00007ffff6633621 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#49 0x00007ffff5dec68e in Gtk::Widget_Class::draw_callback(_GtkWidget*, _cairo*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1
#50 0x00007ffff68dbf9b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#51 0x00007ffff688767f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#52 0x00007ffff62afb6d in g_closure_invoke () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#53 0x00007ffff62c2124 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#54 0x00007ffff62caf43 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#55 0x00007ffff62cbecf in g_signal_emit () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#56 0x00007ffff6894142 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#57 0x00007ffff667e9fa in gtk_container_propagate_draw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#58 0x00007ffff667eacd in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#59 0x00007ffff6630d94 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#60 0x00007ffff6683b5d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#61 0x00007ffff6688832 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#62 0x00007ffff6633621 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#63 0x00007ffff5dec68e in Gtk::Widget_Class::draw_callback(_GtkWidget*, _cairo*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1
#64 0x00007ffff6893fe4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#65 0x00007ffff667e9fa in gtk_container_propagate_draw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#66 0x00007ffff676db7a in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#67 0x00007ffff6683b5d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#68 0x00007ffff6688832 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#69 0x00007ffff6634d9c in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#70 0x00007ffff6688832 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#71 0x00007ffff677039c in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#72 0x00007ffff5de126c in Gtk::Widget::on_draw(Cairo::RefPtr&lt;Cairo::Context&gt; const&amp;) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1
#73 0x00007ffff5dec72f in Gtk::Widget_Class::draw_callback(_GtkWidget*, _cairo*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1
#74 0x00007ffff6893fe4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#75 0x00007ffff667e9fa in gtk_container_propagate_draw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#76 0x00007ffff667eacd in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#77 0x00007ffff6630d94 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#78 0x00007ffff6683b5d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#79 0x00007ffff6688832 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#80 0x00007ffff6633621 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#81 0x00007ffff5de126c in Gtk::Widget::on_draw(Cairo::RefPtr&lt;Cairo::Context&gt; const&amp;) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1
#82 0x00007ffff5dec72f in Gtk::Widget_Class::draw_callback(_GtkWidget*, _cairo*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1
#83 0x00007ffff6893fe4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#84 0x00007ffff667e9fa in gtk_container_propagate_draw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#85 0x00007ffff667eacd in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#86 0x00007ffff68a27b2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#87 0x00007ffff5de126c in Gtk::Widget::on_draw(Cairo::RefPtr&lt;Cairo::Context&gt; const&amp;) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1
#88 0x00007ffff5dec72f in Gtk::Widget_Class::draw_callback(_GtkWidget*, _cairo*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1
#89 0x00007ffff6893fe4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#90 0x00007ffff689d008 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#91 0x00007ffff674bc09 in gtk_main_do_event () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#92 0x00007ffff644b445 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0
#93 0x00007ffff645b996 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0
#94 0x00007ffff645cb06 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0
#95 0x00007ffff645ccc4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0
#96 0x00007ffff62afb6d in g_closure_invoke () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#97 0x00007ffff62c28f3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#98 0x00007ffff62cb882 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#99 0x00007ffff62cbecf in g_signal_emit () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#100 0x00007ffff6454a6d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0
#101 0x00007ffff643fbf8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0
#102 0x00007ffff61d0573 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#103 0x00007ffff61cfae8 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#104 0x00007ffff61cfed8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#105 0x00007ffff61d01d2 in g_main_loop_run () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#106 0x00007ffff4ff1e9c in runtime::loop::run() () from /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/liblinux_utilities.so.8.0.15
#107 0x00007ffff51cef35 in mforms::gtk::UtilitiesImpl::run_cancelable_wait_message(std::__cxx11::basic_string&lt;char, std::char_traits&lt;char&gt;, std::allocator&lt;char&gt; &gt; const&amp;, std::__cxx11::basic_string&lt;char, std::char_traits&lt;char&gt;, std::allocator&lt;char&gt; &gt; const&amp;, std::function&lt;void ()&gt; const&amp;, std::function&lt;bool ()&gt; const&amp;) () from /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libmforms.so.8.0.15
#108 0x00007ffff52181e4 in mforms::Utilities::run_cancelable_task(std::__cxx11::basic_string&lt;char, std::char_traits&lt;char&gt;, std::allocator&lt;char&gt; &gt; const&amp;, std::__cxx11::basic_string&lt;char, std::char_traits&lt;char&gt;, std::allocator&lt;char&gt; &gt; const&amp;, std::function&lt;void* ()&gt; const&amp;, std::function&lt;bool ()&gt; const&amp;, void*&amp;) () from /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libmforms.so.8.0.15
#109 0x00007ffff78747f5 in wb::WBContextSQLIDE::create_connected_editor(grt::Ref&lt;db_mgmt_Connection&gt; const&amp;) () from /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libwbprivate.so.8.0.15
#110 0x00007ffff79d1e39 in wb::WBContext::add_new_query_window(grt::Ref&lt;db_mgmt_Connection&gt; const&amp;, bool) () from /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libwbprivate.so.8.0.15
#111 0x00007ffff79ab549 in wb::WBContextUI::handle_home_action(mforms::HomeScreenAction, base::any const&amp;) () from /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libwbprivate.so.8.0.15
#112 0x00007ffff524a8d7 in mforms::HomeScreen::trigger_callback(mforms::HomeScreenAction, base::any const&amp;) () from /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libmforms.so.8.0.15
#113 0x00007ffff5257bc1 in mforms::ConnectionEntry::activate() () from /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libmforms.so.8.0.15
#114 0x00007ffff5251462 in mforms::ConnectionsSection::mouse_click(mforms::MouseButton, int, int) () from /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libmforms.so.8.0.15
#115 0x00007ffff518ac49 in mforms::gtk::DrawBoxImpl::mouse_button_event(_GdkEventButton*, mforms::DrawBox*) () from /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libmforms.so.8.0.15
#116 0x00007ffff5de3d6b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1
#117 0x00007ffff68dbf9b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#118 0x00007ffff62afb6d in g_closure_invoke () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#119 0x00007ffff62c23ee in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#120 0x00007ffff62caf43 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#121 0x00007ffff62cbecf in g_signal_emit () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#122 0x00007ffff6889b74 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#123 0x00007ffff6749c56 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#124 0x00007ffff674bd73 in gtk_main_do_event () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#125 0x00007ffff644b445 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0
#126 0x00007ffff647c012 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0
#127 0x00007ffff61cfc3e in g_main_context_dispatch () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#128 0x00007ffff61cfed8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#129 0x00007ffff61cff6c in g_main_context_iteration () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#130 0x00007ffff288213d in g_application_run () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#131 0x00005555555de346 in main ()
</pre>
```

Comment: I just ran into this, same exact OS except it's MySQL Workbench 6.3.10.

Comment: This was my error: https://pastebin.com/raw/VTrZjBez

Comment: Interestingly, uninstalling and then downloading the 18.10 .deb from here at least fixes the initial crash: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: Yes I tried with the .deb and it will work until I close, then re-open it.

Comment: @JustinN yes that error is the same one I get when running from bash.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that while my issue was very similar, once I installed MySQL 8, I had to run `sudo mysql_upgrade` to make sure everything was upgraded.  After that and after re-creating the connection, MySQL Workbench worked for me and didn't crash.

Comment: This is interesting because I definitely started experiencing the issue after installing a local instance of MySQL 8.  Might be coincidence because my connections are being made to an RDS instance.

Comment: Just tried this solution and it still crashes without even trying to connect.

Comment: `mysql_upgrade` is deprecated since 8.0.16 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-upgrade.html. Also, @DevonMobley just installed a different app because there was no viable work-around.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is the same issue you had or not or even how much it has to do with anything other than dumb luck. BUT...I removed all of the files in `~./mysql/workbench/cache/` but still failed to stay open. And then removed `connection_id` from `~/.mysql/workbench/sql_history/`.

I was able to load after doing this.